# div popup if button click not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs-bootstrap

I have a button which on clicked shows a dropdown we are using bootstrap to show the dropdown on button click below is my code.

```
 <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Dropdown Example
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

The requirement is that I have to show a div pop up stating system error which will occur only when the button click is not working.

How to check if button click is working or not and show pop up.

The above code is a sample code from w3schools
my main code is written in angularjs and I am using angualar-ui-bootstrap for the drop down. the list values are also coming from the controller.

Comment: are you sending any kind of http request? Cause i cannot understand what you mean by "if button click is not working"

Comment: reproduce it on jsfiddle